# How to print specific value from key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Our teacher set us a challenge to make a program that will allow users to input a symbol of an element and the program should output some info about the element.

To do this I have to use dictionaries. Currently I have this:

```
elements = {"Li": "Lithium" " 12" " Alkali Metal"}
element = input("Enter an elemental symbol: ")
print (elements[element])
```

This prints everything that is related to Li.

I was wondering how I would be able to only output, say Alkali Metal, rather than everything associated with Li? (Yes I know 12 isn't Lithium's atomic number)

Comment: I think your dictionary should be: {"Li": "Lithium", " 12": " Alkali Metal"} . Currently all values are within single key

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: More likely, `{"Li": ("Lithium", "12", "Alkali Metal")}` (or to make the number an actual number, `{"Li": ("Lithium", 12, "Alkali Metal")}`), looks like each key is intended to have three discrete pieces of data associated with it, but the OP doesn't understand string literal concatenation rules and thinks they're associating more than one `str` with that key. Or a nicer alternative to anonymous `tuple`s might be using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) so the values can be accessed as named attributes.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yeah, the OP isn't super clear about how they are determining which piece of information to output. If the field to lookup is being set once and used repeatedly, `operator.attrgetter` might be useful, but that assumes they aren't changing both element and attributes each go round.

Answer (score 6):

You currently have one string as a value so there is not much you can do reliably. You would need to store separate values which you could do with a sub-dict:

```
elements = {"Li": {"full_name":"Lithium", "num":"12", "type":"Alkali Metal"}}
```

Then just access the nested dict using the key of what particular value you want to get:

```
In [1]: elements = {"Li": {"full_name":"Lithium", "num":"12", "type":"Alkali Metal"}}

In [2]: elements["Li"]["num"]
Out[2]: '12'

In [3]: elements["Li"]["full_name"]
Out[3]: 'Lithium'

In [4]: elements["Li"]["type"]
Out[4]: 'Alkali Metal'
```

If you have strings with no comma separating each substring,  python will  create a single string:

```
In [5]: "Lithium" " 12" " Alkali Metal"
Out[5]: 'Lithium 12 Alkali Metal'
In [6]: "Lithium","12","Alkali Metal"
Out[6]: ('Lithium', '12', 'Alkali Metal') # now its a three element tuple
```